# Desaturate and add drop shadow

Tags: css, dropshadow, vendor-prefix

I'm trying to accomplish two things with social sharing icons on a site that I'm working on.

First, I'd like to add a drop shadow. then I would like to have them desaturated by default, and colored on hover.

Below is the code that I'm using:

```
.a2a_floating_style.a2a_vertical_style img {
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(6px 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
    filter: url(#drop-shadow);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=6, OffY=6, Color='#444')";
    filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=6, OffY=6, Color='#444')";
    -webkit-transition:all .4s;
    -moz-transition:all .4s;
    -ms-transition:all .4s;
    -o-transition:all .4s;
    transition:all .4s;
}

.a2a_floating_style.a2a_vertical_style img:not(:hover) {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(6px 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
    filter: url(#drop-shadow);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=6, OffY=6, Color='#444')";
    filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=6, OffY=6, Color='#444')";
    -webkit-filter:grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter:grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter:grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter:grayscale(100%);
    filter:grayscale(100%);
}
.a2a_floating_style.a2a_vertical_style img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(6px 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
    filter: url(#drop-shadow);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=6, OffY=6, Color='#444')";
    filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Dropshadow(OffX=6, OffY=6, Color='#444')";
    -webkit-filter:grayscale(0%);
    -moz-filter:grayscale(0%);
    -ms-filter:grayscale(0%);
    -o-filter:grayscale(0%);
    filter:grayscale(0%);
}
```

It does the saturation bit, but not the drop shadows. If I remove the desaturation instructions, then it does the drop shadow fine.

Is there a way that I ought to organize this so both effects will work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite the filter css, not add a filter to the existing filters. By removing some css lines the problem becomes clear:

```
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(6px 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
```

You can however supply multiple filters by separating them with spaces:

```
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(6px 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)) grayscale(0%);
```